PowerShell XML . (dot) notation, ho to read value of element with attribute?
Good morning i have an XML file and i'm not able to read the inner html of a node with an attribute defined.
file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings>
    <Element1 Attr1="AttrValue1">ElemValue1</Element1>
    <Element2>ElemValue2</Element2>
</Settings>

code:
[XML] $xconf= get-content $XmlFullFilename
write-Host $xconf.Settings.Element1
write-Host $xconf.Settings.Element2

output:
C:\Temp>script.ps1
                   <-- nothing
ElemValue2

But if i remove the attribute from the first element, it works
file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings>
    <Element1>ElemValue1</Element1>
    <Element2>ElemValue2</Element2>
</Settings>

output:
C:\Temp>script.ps1
ElemValue1
ElemValue2

How can i access the first element value, che the elements has an attribute?
I prefer to do it with dot notation (file.section.element.etc....)
Thank you
MAX

I think Santiago covered the better ways to access those elements in your xml file.
Another way to do this while still sticking with dot notation is to explicitly define the field from which you want the data.
write-Host $xconf.Settings.Element1.'#text'

This method explicitly grabs the #text property from the xml.

You can expand on .ChildNodes.InnerText in this case:
$xml.Settings.ChildNodes.InnerText

# Outputs:
# ElemValue1
# ElemValue2

Another option using SelectNodes() could be:
$xml.SelectNodes('/Settings/*/text()').Value


Write-host converts an XmlElement object to a string/InformationRecord (message property is '' in this case).  Better to use write-output or nothing:
$xconf.Settings.Element1

Attr1      #text
-----      -----
AttrValue1 ElemValue1


$xconf.Settings.Element2

ElemValue2

write-host $xconf.Settings.Element1 6>&1 | select *

WriteInformationStream : True
MessageData            :
Source                 : Write-Host
TimeGenerated          : 10/30/2024 1:39:08 PM
Tags                   : {PSHOST}
User                   : AD\js
Computer               : MYCOMP
ProcessId              : 10852
NativeThreadId         : 3956
ManagedThreadId        : 9


tl;dr

The value of .Element2 is a string (the text content of the element, of type [string]), whereas that of .Element1 is a System.Xml.XmlElement instance, for the reasons explained in the next section.

That Write-Host emits an empty line when given a System.Xml.XmlElement instance is a bug - see GitHub issue #24508; omit Write-Host[1] and you'll see a representation of the element's child nodes.

There is no unified purely property-based way that guarantees that .<ChildElementName> always returns the text content of a given element, but you can combine indexed access with .InnerText:

The existing answers offer workarounds for extracting the text content; let me add some more:

If you know that the property of interest contains an XmlElement instance, use .InnerText (.'#text' works too, and while it is more obscure and less convenient to type, it's actually the first tab completion offered):
 $xconf.Settings.Element1.InnerText


Unified approaches, where you ensure that all child elements are accessed as XmlElement instances; that is, the following approaches work analogously with the attribute-less <Element2> element:
 # By element name using an *index expression* (['...'])
 # rather than property access.
 # If the target element has a namespace prefix, use the prefixed name.
 $xconf.Settings['Element1'].InnerText

 # By child node *position* (0-based index):
 $xconf.Settings.ChildNodes[0].InnerText

 # Using XPath, but note that this would require 
 # explicit *namespace handling* in XML documents using namespaces,
 # which requires much more effort.
 $xconf.Settings.SelectSingleNode('Element1').InnerText








Background information:

PowerShell's adaption of the XML DOM provided by the .NET ([xml]) class - described in detail in this answer - represents XML child elements (as well as XML attributes) as if they were (namespace-less) properties, allowing for convenient OO access.

The type of such adapted (virtual) properties varies, depending on whether a given XML element is a simple one (has no XML attributes and only a text child node) or a complex one (has at least one XML attribute and/or child elements):

A simple element is represented by the value of its text child node, i.e. the string content of the element, and is therefore of type [string].

In your case, simple element <Element2> therefore translated into property .Element2 whose value is the element's text content (the value of the child text node), 'ElemValue2'.


A complex element is represented as an element object, i.e. as a(n adapted) System.Xml.XmlElement instance.

In your case, complex element <Element1> therefore translated into property .Element1 whose value is the XML element object itself, i.e. a System.Xml.XmlElement instance.

This would have been more obvious if you had output $xconf.Settings.Element1 alone, instead of using Write-Host[1], due to the bug reported in GitHub issue #24508; outputting it alone (i.e. directly to the success output stream with the usual rich for-display formatting) yields the following:
Attr1      #text
-----      -----
AttrValue1 ElemValue1


That is, the XmlElement instance has two adapted properties, which are the only ones that print; the type-native ones (e.g., Name) do not; therefore, somewhat confusingly, the name of the element itself does not print:

Attr1 represents the element's attribute of that name.
#text is the text child node, which is technically an instance of [System.Xml.XmlText] whose .Name property value is '#text', which PowerShell's DOM adaptation uses as the property name.




The rationale for these situational type variations is presumably the following:

PowerShell's XML DOM adaptation is focused on simple OO access (drilling down into a document tree with dot notation), with both child elements and attributes available as properties.
Conceiving of a simple element as just representing its text content is convenient: by definition you know the element name, and in terms of the element's content the only other thing of interest is its text (child node) content, so the latter is returned.
By contrast, a complex element requires a "subtree" approach, so that an element's attributes and/or child elements can be accessed.






[1] As an aside: Write-Host is typically the wrong tool to use, unless the intent is to write to the display only, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it by itself; e.g, $value, instead of Write-Host $value (or use Write-Output $value); see this answer. To explicitly print only to the display but with rich formatting, use Out-Host.

